# Google maps not visible when installed from apk

Tags: android, eclipse, google-maps

When I install android apk file then the google map is not visible but when I run the same code from eclipse then maps are visible. I have given all the permissions in the android menifest file.

This is my menifest file-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.majhe.android"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<!-- Permissions that are required for retrieving map data -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<!-- Permissions that are recommended for using map and location services -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />


<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />

<!-- Recommended: prevents app installation if required level of Open GL is not supported -->
<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.majhe.android.LoginActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_login"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.majhe.android.HomeActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_home"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.majhe.android.EditProfileActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_edit_profile"
        android:parentActivityName="com.majhe.android.HomeActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.majhe.android.EmergencyContactsActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_emergency_contacts"
        android:parentActivityName="com.majhe.android.HomeActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.majhe.android.IntroScreenSlide"
        android:label="Majhe v1.2"
        android:parentActivityName="com.majhe.android.HomeActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyAS0_nm-fW_Wu7pNjxM3G2w9FxK_hbsCsI" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
</application>
```

Comment: have you put right key in your application?

Comment: Did you changed the API Key?

Comment: First un-install the app from device and then install it again, and if you are installing signed apk file then you have to create new google api key for signed apk hash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1)Creating the SHA-1 for your signature key.**

```
The Eclipse debug key for signing your application can be found in the userhome/.android/debug.keystore file. eg) C:\Users\nil pc43.android\debug.keystore

----->  C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_01\bin\keytool.exe -v -list -alias androiddebugkey -keystore "C:\Users\Info 1234\.android\debug.keystore" -storepass     
android -keypass android


Example)
    C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_01\bin>keytool.exe -v -list -alias androiddebugkey -keystore "c:\Users\nil pc43\.android\deb
    ug.keystore" -storepass android -keypass android
    Alias name: androiddebugkey
    Creation date: Apr 4, 2013
    Entry type: PrivateKeyEntry
    Certificate chain length: 1
    Certificate[1]:
    Owner: CN=Android Debug, O=Android, C=US
    Issuer: CN=Android Debug, O=Android, C=US
    Serial number: 4a5b5c6d
            Valid from: Thu Apr 04 18:33:13 IST 2013 until: Sat Mar 28 18:33:13 IST 2043
    Certificate fingerprints:
             MD5:  51:CE:5C:07:05:31:98:6A:D5:7C:24:B1:B3:EC:22:A3
             SHA1: B2:68:A7:D6:3A:FC:8F:15:8D:3E:1F:4A:E8:99:CE:8D:F5:28:07:4D
             SHA256: 5B:5B:FE:7B:92:7F:06:53:1E:28:BB:D0:E5:CB:05:46:B0:81:76:CC:61:87:97:FA:19:68:B6:C1:08:E8:D6:D9
             Signature algorithm name: SHA256withRSA
             Version: 3
```

**2)Register with the Google APIs Console**

```
-----> https://code.google.com/apis/console/
 ----> Go to Services 
Then Activate(ON) the Google Maps Android API v2.
```

**3)Create key for your application**

```
-----> sELECT  API ACCESS
**You need later to register your application via its package in this console together
with the SHA-1 fingerprint of your signature key. For this you  select the entry and
click on the API Access entry. Afterwards click on the Create new Android key...entry.**

-----> Click on "Create New Android KEY"
-----> Enter your SHA-1 fingerprint and the package of your application separated by a semicolon. 

   For example you can use the com.example.mymaps package. (your SHA-1 key;package Name)
```

**4)Change Your Manifist.xml and JAVA File according below link**

```
-----> please Reffer this Link
http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidGoogleMaps/article.html
```

**5)Now Create new KeyStore File and APK file For your project.**

```
----->C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_01\bin>keytool -list -alias "your alias name" -keystore  "path that have keystor file of yor application"
Enter keystore password: <pasword of your keystore>
mapExample, Apr 18, 2013, PrivateKeyEntry,
Certificate fingerprint (SHA1): 71:EF:B0:6A:A8:BG:E5:61:E9:23:D0:F2:1E:9D:D0:6F:A4:70:0F:A9

-----> Now you have new SHA-1 KEY 
-----> With this SHA-1 KEY, Follow the Step no 4
```

**6)Now you will get NEW google map API KEY**

```
Now use this key in to Manifeast.xml file (AS SHOWN IN STEM NO 4)

<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
    android:value="NEW GOOGLE MAP API KEY" />
```

**7)Now Create New APK FILE of you APLICATION with the use the existing keystore.**

Comment: So the android menifest file should have the key generated from the step no 6 then what is the use of step no 4

Comment: Yes, at last key should be equal in keystore and api