# maps not getting displayed

Tags: java, android, google-maps-android-api-2

i tried all possible solution by using debug/custom keystore.but nothing worked.
here is my xml file
my android manifest file:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.testapp.act.Home"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" ></uses-library>


    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyDP_I4FFz5i-Dr-YrfeSxWbMteShUcvV18" />
   </application>
   <uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />
```

main.xml
      `<fragment
          android:id="@+id/map"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:layout_below="@+id/relativetop"
          android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>`
 
if any one of you have a solution of this so please let me know

Comment: what is your logcat said???? It should.

Comment: might be your map_key is not valid. please generate map_key for keystore which you are using.

Comment: Are you trying in emulator or in real device ?

Comment: also use realease version of your app not the debug build

Comment: try to refer this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23909567)!. You should so somthing like they said.

Comment: i'm trying in real device

Comment: my logcat gives me error :                                                                    Failed to load map. Error contacting Google servers.

Comment: i solved my problem thans

Answer (score 1):

You should use `com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment` instead of `com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment`. I have an answer on [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20830610/android-google-map-api-v2-unfortunately-application-has-stopped-force-clos/20840757#20840757). You can check it for how to use `SupportMapFragment`.

Good luck.